# I cannot break with GDB and QEMU

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gdb, kernel, qemu

I am debugging the Linux Kernel (latest version) using **GDB and QEMU**.

I have set **DEBUG_INFO to yes** in the configuration file.

Here is how I call QEMU:

`$> qemu-system-x86_64 -snapshot -m 4G -serial stdio -kernel ~/Documents/kernel/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -initrd ~/D\
ocuments/kernel/initrd/initrd_x86_64.gz -append "root=/dev/sda1 ignore_loglevel" -s`

And GDB of course:

`$> gdb vmlinux`

Then inside gdb:

`(gdb)> target remote :1234`

So nothing amazing.

It stops QEMU. I set my breakpoints, which seems to work as usual, and I type "continue". The QEMU execution resumes.

But then, even if my function is reached (I see the kernel message printk I set inside the function), gdb does not stop.

`$> qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.12.0 (Debian 1:2.12+dfsg-3)
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers`

And

`$> gdb --version
GNU gdb (Debian 8.1-4) 8.1`

I don't know what to try next.
Any help would be appreciated.

PS: for information, I am writing a keylogger as a Linux driver. So I am registering a new keyboard notifier, and this is the keyboard notifier that is failing.

PS2: I also tried what they recommend here [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285660/gdb-ignores-breakpoint-in-qemu-bootloader) about setting hardware breakpoints instead, but it did not change anything, same problem.

Thank you.

Julien